# Why this code is not valid for all the test cases for median of two sorted arrays , passing only some of them?

Tags: java, median

**Why is this code not valid for all the testcases only passing some of them?**

```
public class Solution {
public double findMedianSortedArrays(final List<Integer> a, final List<Integer> b) {
    int n1=a.size();
    int n2=b.size();
    if(n1>n2)
      findMedianSortedArrays(b,a);
    if(n1==0 && n2==0)
      return 0;

      if(n1==0)
      {
          if(n2%2==0)
          {
           return (double)(b.get((b.size()-1)/2)+b.get(b.size()/2))/2;   
          }
          return (double)b.get(b.size()/2);
      }
    int low=0;
    int high=n1;
    while(low<high)
    {
        int partitionX=(low+high)/2;
        int partitionY=(n1+n2+1)/2-partitionX;
        int maxLeftX=((partitionX==0)?Integer.MIN_VALUE:a.get(partitionX-1));
        int minRightX=((partitionX==n1)?Integer.MAX_VALUE:a.get(partitionX));
        int maxLeftY=((partitionY==0)?Integer.MIN_VALUE:b.get(partitionY-1));
        int minRightY=((partitionY==n2)?Integer.MAX_VALUE:b.get(partitionY));
        if(maxLeftX<minRightY && maxLeftY<minRightX)
        {
            if((n1+n2)%2==0)
            {
                return (double)(Math.max(maxLeftX,maxLeftY)+Math.min(minRightX,minRightY))/2;

            }
            return (double)Math.max(maxLeftX,maxLeftY);
        }
        else if(maxLeftX>minRightY)
          high=partitionX-1;
        else
           low=partitionX+1;
    }
     return 0;  
   }
}
```

Comment: please tag language

Comment: We don't know your (failing) test cases. It's difficult to help.

Comment: A : [ -43, -25, -18, -15, -10, 9, 39, 40 ]
B : [ -2 ]  falling for this input